Great expectations core : Cannot convert column into bool spark error
i am trying to get batch , however i keep facing the following error :
Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
my code is a just one line and the database is only string columns !
I am running the code on a notebook on databricks.
i am just trying to create a batch so i can run some expectations.
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

okk , so basically i am just following the steps on the doc for great expectations , i have a set of table on unity catalogue , i read one table using spark , and when i try to get batch i get the above error.
